# Could the sun be used as a particle accelerator?

Tags: magnetic-fields, sun, large-hadron-collider

Large particle colliders require a lot of energy, and inputing more and more energy usually produce more and more interesting results.

Assuming that the required collider, detectors, etc. can be transported and operated safely at a some safe but useful distance to the sun, could the sun magnetic field be used to collide particles on a determined detector target?

I imagine one could just put a detector at some place and use a natural stream of particle coming from the sun. Would such a safe place even exists, while still allowing for useful experiments?

Comment: How would the particles be accelerated?

Comment: Search terms: magnetic reconnection, coronal mass ejection.

Comment: The charged particles coming from the sun are on very chaotic trajectories, there wouldn't be any way to get accurate repeatable results.

Answer (score 1):

We use the particle output of the sun right now, more or less as you propose, to strengthen our understanding of neutrinos.

Note that the idea of using extraterrestrial particles like cosmic rays from deep space to do particle physics is generating significant interest, since those particles sometimes carry far more energy than any particle accelerator in the world could ever do, and the cosmos furnishes us with those particles for free.